Neovim config lazy.lua file error on moving the file to its parent's directory
I had my lazy.lua file in .config/nvim/lua/{name}/ directory and then to structure my config I moved it to .config/nvim/lua. After that I got some errors basically about nil values in some lazy files.
All these errors originate from
require('lazy').setup('plugins')
These errors will disappear once I move lazy.lua back to .config/nvim/lua/{name}/ directory.
I obviously updated all the imports in init.lua file. I also tried re-installing lazy by sudo rm ~/.local/share/nvim/lazy ~/.local/state/nvim/lazy -rf, also deleted lazy-lock.json file but nothing works except moving lazy.lua to .config/nvim/lua/{name}/ directory. I even updated neovim to latest version.
Here is my lazy.lua file:
-- Bootstrap lazy.nvim
local lazypath = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/lazy/lazy.nvim"
if not (vim.uv or vim.loop).fs_stat(lazypath) then
  local lazyrepo = "https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim.git"
  print('installing lazy...')
  local out = vim.fn.system({ "git", "clone", "--filter=blob:none", "--branch=stable", lazyrepo, lazypath })
  if vim.v.shell_error ~= 0 then
    vim.api.nvim_echo({
      { "Failed to clone lazy.nvim:\n", "ErrorMsg" },
      { out, "WarningMsg" },
      { "\nPress any key to exit..." },
    }, true, {})
    vim.fn.getchar()
    os.exit(1)
  end
end
vim.opt.rtp:prepend(lazypath)

print('lazy installed')

-- Make sure to setup `mapleader` and `maplocalleader` before
-- loading lazy.nvim so that mappings are correct.
-- This is also a good place to setup other settings (vim.opt)
vim.g.mapleader = " "
vim.g.maplocalleader = "\\"

-- Setup lazy.nvim
require("lazy").setup('plugins')

Here are the errors:-
In Older version 0.9.4

ERROR Failed to run healthcheck for "lazy" plugin. Exception:
function health#check, line 25
Vim(eval):E5108: Error executing lua
...al/share/nvim/lazy/lazy.nvim/lua/lazy/manage/process.lua:52: attempt to index   upvalue 'uv' (a >nil value)
stack traceback:
.local/share/nvim/lazy/lazy.nvim/lua/lazy/manage/process.lua:52: in function 'spawn'
.local/share/nvim/lazy/lazy.nvim/lua/lazy/manage/process.lua:234: in function 'exec'
.local/share/nvim/lazy/lazy.nvim/lua/lazy/health.lua:40: in function 'have'
.local/share/nvim/lazy/lazy.nvim/lua/lazy/health.lua:72: in function 'check'
[string "luaeval()"]:1: in main chunk

In Latest version 0.11.0

lazy.nvim
{lazy.nvim} version 11.14.1
OK {git} version 2.34.1
OK no existing packages found by other package managers

OK packer_compiled.lua not found
ERROR No plugins loaded. Did you forget to run require("lazy"). setup()?



Luarocks
ERROR Failed to run healthcheck for "lazy" plugin. Exception:
.local/share/nvim/lazy/lazy.nvim/lua/lazy/health.lua:132: attempt to index field 'rocks' (a nil value)


Firstly, the "rocks" check health error is likely because you don't have LuaRocks installed on your system. LuaRocks is a requirement for lazy.nvim so that it can install rockspecs. You can either install it, or disable its use in lazy.nvim by uncommenting the line rocks = { enabled = false }, below.
Secondly, by moving lazy.lua from ~/.config/nvim/lua/config to ~/.config/nvim/lua, you've inadvertently created a name clash between your lazy.lua file and the lazy module ~/.local/share/nvim/lazy.
The solution is to rename ~/.config/nvim/lua/lazy.lua to something other than lazy.lua, or put it in some {name} directory like you've done prior. Renaming the file to something simple and read-able like lazy-config.lua will suffice.
More concretely, assuming you want the following structured setup, you need the three things listed below.
~/.config/nvim
├── init.lua
└── lua
    ├── lazy-config.lua
    └── plugins
        ├── spec1.lua
        ├── **
        └── spec2.lua


Ensure the ~/.config/nvim/init.lua file exists, and calls the following function:

require("lazy-config")


Ensure the directory ~/.config/nvim/lua directory exists, and within that directory, there is the lazy-config.lua file which contains at least the following code:

-- Bootstrap lazy.nvim
local lazypath = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/lazy/lazy.nvim"
if not (vim.uv or vim.loop).fs_stat(lazypath) then
  local lazyrepo = "https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim.git"
  local out = vim.fn.system({ "git", "clone", "--filter=blob:none", "--branch=stable", lazyrepo, lazypath })
  if vim.v.shell_error ~= 0 then
    vim.api.nvim_echo({
      { "Failed to clone lazy.nvim:\n", "ErrorMsg" },
      { out, "WarningMsg" },
      { "\nPress any key to exit..." },
    }, true, {})
    vim.fn.getchar()
    os.exit(1)
  end
end
vim.opt.rtp:prepend(lazypath)

-- Make sure to setup `mapleader` and `maplocalleader` before
-- loading lazy.nvim so that mappings are correct.
-- This is also a good place to setup other settings (vim.opt)
vim.g.mapleader = " "
vim.g.maplocalleader = "\\"

-- Setup lazy.nvim
require("lazy").setup({
  spec = {
    -- import your plugins
    { import = "plugins" },
  },
  -- Configure any other settings here. See the documentation (https://lazy.folke.io/configuration) for more details.
  -- colorscheme that will be used when installing plugins.
  install = { colorscheme = { "habamax" } },
  -- automatically check for plugin updates
  checker = { enabled = true },
  -- disable luarocks if it is not available on system
  -- rocks = { enabled = false },
})


Ensure the directory ~/.config/nvim/plugins exists, where each file within that directory contains the specifications of a plugin you want to install, returned via a table. For example, to install lualine, you'd create a lualine.lua file within ~/.config/nvim/plugins that contains the following:

return { -- Status line for Neovim
    "nvim-lualine/lualine.nvim",
    opts = {
        options = {
            icons_enabled = false,
            component_separators = "|",
            section_separators = "",
        },
        sections = {
            lualine_x = {
                "encoding",
                "filetype",
            },
        lualine_c = {
                { "filename", path = 3 },
            },
        },
    },
}

Read more about lazy.nvim installation here.
